# Which modern firearm should a time traveler bring to be easily reproducible for a historic civilization?

Tags: science-based, time-travel, firearms

Eureka! Our hero just discovered the secret of time travel, but what to do with it? "I know!", he says. "I will travel back in time as far as I can and hand them a modern firearm. They will learn how it works, and they will be technologically superior and dominate the world with me as their leader!"

At least, that's the idea.

## The Time Machine

The Time Machine is a rough prototype, so it is best not to travel back and forth too often. In fact, once jumped back in time enough, it's possible that you can't ever jump back forward. As a result, the hero cannot just continuously jump back and forth in time to transport a lot of modern equipment. He has one chance, and one chance only.

Furthermore, the Time Machine is able to travel through time and, contrary to the name, space. The Time Machine can pick any past date, time and location, and the Time Machine would bring the hero there. It is not perfectly accurate though, so you might end a year sooner or later, or somewhere within a kilometer of the target.

## The Hero

Our Hero is a scientist, but not a brilliant engineer. While he does have rudimentary knowledge of firearms, he cannot perfectly describe what every single component of the gun does, nor how it is produced. He might be able to explain that a striker works by using a spring to propel a metal stick against the primer, which explodes, in turn ignites the powder and thus propels the bullet forward.

He is also not a chemist. He doesn't know how modern smokeless powder is made, but he did look up how old black powder was made and he is reasonably certain he could explain the process, if necessary.

Speaking of explanations and speaking about things, our Hero is also a gifted linguist and able to speak any language, old and new, to a good enough degree that he could express even more technical concepts to native speakers.

## The Goal

Our Hero wants to bring any modern firearm - a pistol, an automatic rifle, a shotgun, etc. - as well as a reasonable amount of appropriate ammo - with him into the past. Our Hero wagers that he would have the biggest chance of success of dominating the world if he would travel in time further back. As such, our Hero wants to pick a gun that even a rather old - by whatever comparison - civilization could reproduce in a good enough quality.

One can assume that the Hero is patient, so if the good people of that time require a year or two to understand the firearms, that is acceptable too, as long as it results in them being able to make the firearm afterwards.

The required time is also not very important. Equipping an army takes time, and our hero knows that. So if arming an entire army with firearms takes several months or even years, so be it.

We can further assume that our Hero brings enough Gold with him - a currency that is universally accepted anywhere - should the need to pay someone arise.

## The Task

- Which firearm should our Hero bring with him, and why?
- How far back in time could he go, before even the simplest modern firearm would be so technologically outlandish, that not even the most skilled scientists and engineers of the time would be able to reproduce it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96469/discussion-on-question-by-mechmk1-which-modern-firearm-should-a-time-traveler-br).

Comment: Giving gun tech to people who wouldn't know how to build them properly seems like a very bad idea. Funny thing is, if time travel is real, this kinda thing [may already have happened](https://darwinawards.com/legends/legends2001-01.html).

Comment: You need to re-think the question.  Making the guns is not really the problem, at least if you have competent metalworkers.  The problem with any modern firearm is producing the ammunition.  You have to figure out how to make brass cartridges to precise tolerances, and how to make primers that go off when the firing pin hits them, but not otherwise.

Comment: > It is not perfectly accurate though, so you might end a year sooner or later, or somewhere within a kilometer of the target.


I don't know what is worse: Coming out a kilometer above ground level, or a kilometer below ground level :)

Comment: @Fels Below ground level is definitely worse. Above ground can be survivable with a parachute, whereas being trapped a kilometer below ground is a guaranteed death sentence.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to speed run world conquest in a single lifetime, if you are keeping the guns to a small number of loyal tribes, you would be facing rebellions of 100 to 1, and you ammunition production wouldn't be able to keep up. If you try to recruit from or move production to the conquered people, you will end up with the same problem, but now they have guns. Most empires colapse shortly after the founder die, and they usually have to move their attention inwards to keep it together for that long

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Unless he's an expert metallurgist the biggest issue you're going to have isn't in terms of producing the parts; anyone with a drill and a hand file (or some rocks that will serve the purpose) and enough patience can make a gun from a solid block of appropriate metal and therein lies the problem. Modern weapons require modern alloys, many of which are proprietary products that the character cannot know the recipe for. Furthermore the fineness of measurement necessary to make them if the recipe is known has only existed for a few decades, some of these alloys require measurements in the parts per million.

All is not lost however, you can take some weapons that are currently antiques back a lot farther than you'd think. Assuming your character knows how to make reliable gunpowder that is. You could take a [Culverin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culverin) back to 3300BC [Anatolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatolia) and be able to reproduce it in local [bronze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bronze).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96424/discussion-on-answer-by-ash-which-modern-firearm-should-a-time-traveler-bring-to).

Comment: It doesn't even have to be _very_ antique; with enough patience and a skilled crafter working from sufficiently-detailed blueprints, you could reproduce an 1860 Henry in Julius Caesar's Rome.

Comment: Culverins would certainly not be a world domination weapon in 3300BC.  They were so inaccurate that they were meant to be fired at near point-blank ranges.  They were specialty weapons meant for penetrating a knight's armor, but in 3300BC armor is not much of a factor; so, the 1 thing they are really good at would not even be a requirement.  Even the bows and javelins of the late stone age would outperform a culverin once you take armor out of the equation.

Answer (score 52):

**Bring the Tools, not the Weapons**

The hard part here is getting the precision tooling you will need done right.  Rifling a barrel and pressing ammunition is pretty darn hard without the right equipment, but all the tools needed to set up a fire-arms and munitions workshop take up surprisingly little space.

Since he has enough wealth in the 21st century to acquire significant amounts of gold and build a time-machine,  I'm assuming he's fairly wealthy.  Although he lacks mechanical engineering skills himself, he could prepare for his mission by hiring proper engineers to modify hobbyist gun making kits to rely on non-electrical power sources such as foot-pedals or a water wheel, and help him design weapons to the specifications of the alloys that will be available to him in the past.

Before he goes back, he should then run tests making his own home-made bronze, gun powder, ignition caps, etc. to test his ability to make sound weapons from what will be local resources.

**The Time & Place**

For this I'd suggest going to Ancient Athens at ~600 BCE.

While most historical guns were made of cast iron or steel, bronze is actually a fairly good material for making firearms, because it can be caste without being brittle.  A revolutionary era bronze cannon was half the weight of the cast iron cannons of the time.  Steel did not really get good enough to outperform bronze as a gun-making material until the 1800s, so your time traveler should head back to a civilization that is proficient in bronze working before gunpowder was first invented.  This means that in the you will have a good material to work with and be able to control the means of producing and distributing the ammo so that even if another nation reverse engineers your gun, they won't have the means to make the ammo.

While 600 BCE was technically after the Bronze Age collapse, bronze was still widely used at this time since Athens re-established the trade routes that made bronze possible again.  While bronze was not their preferred alloy in weapon/armor making as it was in the Mycenean Period, it was still prominently used in their artwork; so, there still would have been a large number of skilled bronze craftsmen.

The biggest reason to pick Athens though over an older, true bronze age civilization is that bronze age civilizations were pretty exclusively ruled by nobilities or theocracies such that you could never gain a position of power among the people as an outsider. No matter how good your tech is, you would never be more than the ruler's slave.  In Ancient Greece, money could buy political power.  You could raise your self up to be a general, and use the influence of your conquests to eventually usurp or at least strongly control the democracy.

Athens also has a relatively large population in a small place with lots of allied city states.  This gives you the manpower you need to expand far.

**The Currency**

You may want to exchange most of your gold for silver before you go.  At today's market value, gold has an 80:1 exchange rate with silver, but in ancient Greece, the exchange rate would be anywhere from about 13:1 to 1:3 just depending.  Silver (and not gold) was the standard currency in ancient Athens and the preferred coinage for international trade on the Mediterranean (4.3g was worth 1 day's labor).  Greeks specifically did not like being payed in gold due to efforts by Persia to devalue their silver coinage by intentionally fixing the exchange rate of gold and silver to prefer their coinage at the 13:1 ratio, even though gold was considered less valuable than silver in Greece.  So, definitely bring some gold for any materials you need to buy from Persian merchants, but silver is the way to go for local labor and materials.

**The Weapon he Makes**

To dominate the ancient world, your weapon needs a few qualities that not all historical firearms could achieve.  While older firearms like culivans, muskets, and arquebuses offer some specific advantages over bows and crossbows that made them successful in their own hay day, their advantages are not significant enough to really make them "world domination" weapons. Instead, your minimum firearm should be something that is so much better than older weapons that even archery cultures like the Ancient Cretans, Persians, or Parthians would be at a distinct disadvantage since these cultures could arguably out range war most early gunpowder armies.

First, it will need to be able to kill through the shields and armor of the time period you go back to.  This significantly limits the effectiveness of most shotguns and low caliber firearms since available resources will likely not be able to achieve the muzzle velocity and armor penetration of modern munitions.  Before the invention of more complex gunpowders like guncotton, nearly all firearms were .45cal or larger for this reason.

Secondly, it will need range.  To have a true tactical advantage, you will need to be able to shoot down enemy archers, slingers, and crossbowmen before they can start shooting at you.  Most muskets are only target accurate at 100m and area accurate up to 300m (similar to ancient bows).   More primitive firearms like early culverins and fire lances were only target accurate within a few paces making them no more accurate than an untrained archer. Even though they had a theoretical range of 600m they were not even considered area accurate at these sorts of distances.  The feature that really made guns hands-down better than of bows and crossbows was the invention of riffling.  Even primitive rifles could give you target accuracy in the 700-1800m range.

Third, you will need a enough rate of fire that your armies will get in many shots before your enemies can close range enough to take away your advantages.  Automatic firing systems might be too complicated to reproduce since you may not be able to produce high precision parts, but revolvers can be made to relatively low tolerances. Also, if individual bullets prove to be too much work to make, a removable revolver cylinder like that found on the Colt Paterson would allow one to pre-pack cylinders to more or less the same effect as having clips of bullets.

The hardest part is going to be primer caps.  While your time traveler may struggle to make these himself, all the chemicals required to make a primitive Mercury Fulminate (mercury, potassium nitrate, green vitriol, and ethanol) have all been known about and used since ancient times; so, an ancient apothecary with a little bit of guidance could probably solve this problem.  If not, a sort of flint-lock mechanism could be employed, though it may be a bit less convenient/reliable.

[image]

The final weapon will likely resemble the Whitworth Rifle as suggests UIDAlexD in terms of accuracy, calbre, and muzzle velocity.  The addition of a revolver cylinder may slightly reduce the weapon's accuracy, but you'd still be way outranging bows, and the increased rate of fire would more than be worth it.

Comment: This. The thing that a lot of people overlook is that the longbow was a massively superior weapon in most respects to early and even middle period firearms in terms of range, stopping power and rate of fire; it's just that it was much easier to teach masses of people to point a musket in roughly the right direction and pull the trigger than it was to train people into competent bowmen.

Comment: @Shadur Plus, once you no longer need the army, you can just take the guns away.  With bowmen, you tan take away the longbow - then they just have very strong arms and a variety of easy to access club-like objects.  Your reign might be cut significantly shorter than expected...

Comment: To the point of penetration, smaller calibers are actually preferred, as they focus their energy into a smaller area. 5.56x45/5.45x39/5.7x28 are fantastic armor penetrators because of their high speed and small cross section. Also, while it may be lacking against modern rifle-rated armor, I'd fully expect a 12 Gauge Slug/00 Buck to effectively ignore any ancient plate armor.

Comment: @UIDAlexD Roman slings used the principle of not caring if you could penetrate armor.  A higher mass and lower velocity would cause fatal internal bleeding through plate armor.  As for your listed calibres, those work great for modern firearms, but getting to those muzzle velocities without modern machinery and alloys is unlikely. which is why I suggested following the mass over quality approach.

Comment: @Nosajimiki True, but that's not my point. Saying that the need for penetration rules out small calibers is flatly untrue. Also there's the case of the Whitworth Rifle, which is accurate even by modern standards despite being nearly two centuries old. Very good fit out-ranging and eliminating archers.

Comment: The Whitworth is a .45 cal rifle. Both a good argument for my speculations about bullet size and need of rifling. Infact, less than .45 cal was very uncommon for anything other than small game guns until the 1900s.  Also, it's construction used industrial era steel. While not nearly as good as modern steel, the iron available in the ancient world would not have been up to that quality which is why I argue for bronze if you want to go back to before ~200 years ago.

Comment: If your hero could make modern quality slugs, gunpowder, and barrels, I would agree that low cal would be best, but a 5.56x45 nato round has 3.6 times the muzzle velocity of a Whitworth riffled musket, and even matching the fit and gunpowder quality of a Whitworth with bronze aged resources seems a bit difficult.

Comment: @Nosajimiki: UIDAlexD is responding to your answer, where you wrote, "First, it will need good penetration so it can go through the shields and armor of the ancient world." If you no longer believe that to be the case, then you should edit your answer instead of rebutting it.

Answer (score 17):

Firearms require a social and industrial ecosystem to exist. Modern weapons with metal cartridges could not exist before the development of deep draw dies and the skilled workers to use them. Even as late as the 1860's (American Civil War) cartridges were paper cylinders holding the powder and the ball, but now you need a cheap source of paper (and preferably waxed paper to protect the contents).

This process is "rinse and repeat" in any age, gunpowder was described as early as the 9th century AD and the very first primitive firearms appeared shortly thereafter. Improvements in the formulation of gunpowder required improvements in metallurgy and manufacturing to take advantage of them (the etymology of "barrel" is exactly what you think: the early gun barrels were made is the same manner as wooden barrels...).

> The first firearms were made at a time when metallurgy was not advanced enough to cast tubes capable of withstanding the explosive forces of early cannons, so the pipe (often built from staves of metal) needed to be braced periodically along its length for reinforcement, producing an appearance somewhat reminiscent of storage barrels being stacked together, hence the English name.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKtSj.png)

For all practical purposes, an arquebus or other matchlock weapon is probably within the skillsets of trained workers as far back as the late 1300's or early 1400's

[image]

*Hand Gonne in the 1300's*

[image]

*Matchlock firearm*

However, even jumping forward a few centuries with a matchlock isn't going to do the mad scientist much good. The production of gunpowder and firearms is essentially the domain of a few skilled craftsmen, the economy isn't going to support the large scale production of firearms and the tactics needed to *effectively* use firearms also needs to be developed, along with the logistical infrastructure to support firearms (imagine transporting tons of gunpowder across Europe in the 1300's...). Indeed, these sorts of firearms require a specific set of tactics (sometimes known as "Pike and shot") to allow the gunners to be effective against mounted cavalry.

[image]

*Pike and shot army*

So in isolation, the knowledge of advanced firearms alone isn't going to do much good. There must be an economy with enough capacity to produce the firearms, gunpowder, skilled craftsmen, transport (carts, horses, special containers to limit fire and explosion risks), sergeants and officers to develop and train troops in the right tactics...Your mad scientist will need to bring an immense illustrated library and probably an entire team of expert instructors in many different fields in order to make real changes to history.

Comment: Straight wall black powder cartridges could be, and were, made by soldering a solder-seamed tube to a lathe turned head.  The earliest cartridges (dating to before 1820!) were made this way, and could be mass produced in "factories" with women and children in place of machines.  If you can bore a barrel, you have the technology to make the heads, and jewelers were soldering metals in ancient times.

Comment: While this is indeed possible, the cost would by pretty fantastic. While these sorts of cartridges were being made in 1820, armies were using paper cartridges by the millions into the 1860's.

Comment: Cost has never mattered to a conquering force.  The reason these cartridges weren't in use prior to the 1860s was because the gun they went to wasn't picked up by a military buyer and only a few hundred were made.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Cost absolutely matters to a conquering force, that is the reason they did not outfit their entire armies with plate armor, I would bankrupt them before they even set out to fight. Cost ALWAYS matters in war.

Comment: Plate armor wasn't widely used because average foot soldiers would have been less effective in it (due to weight and lack of training in working around the movement restrictions).  It could have been made fairly cheaply and to a "three sizes" model, if it were wanted/needed in quantity.  If cost trumps effectiveness, why would Napoleon's (and Washington's) armies have used paper cartridges instead of loose ammunition?

Comment: Plate armour was used by Roman legions, but eventually superseded as warfare evolved and the Roman Armies became more cavalry oriented. Foot soldiers needed different protection and tactics in order to survive in this environment. Compare late Imperial armies against the early Empire or the armies of the *Res Publica Roma*

Answer (score 9):

Nothing.

No modern firearm or ammunition will pass for an ancient one. Every speck of metal and every chemical trace will make it stand out as not belonging.  Worse no one is reproducing modern firearms or ammunition prior to the ~1800's and metal lathes, chemistry, and precision measurement.

Basically if they can make a firearm, they are already making said firearms. If you want to advance technology you need to come in with the specialized knowledge involved you can't just hand them something and say make this, because the answer will be "how?" especially if chemistry is involved and it almost always is.

Comment: As a small caveat, it should be possible to make the next incremental advances; normally these are possible, technological. For example, for most of the smooth-bore musket life it was possible to introduce rifling... but you're not advancing to WWI firearms during the 1500s.

Comment: Precision measurement being the major hurdle.

Comment: @Ash And part tolerance, which is a stranger beast than you might think. There has been two modern efforts to restore WWII B-52 bombers to flight, and both faced the same problem: Milling had become so precise that they were actually *too* precise, and the parts didn't work in the bombers designed for WWI equipment. They had to rebuild WWII era milling equipment with WWII era slop to build the replacement parts for the bombers.

Comment: @NexTerren possibly but since the person admittedly does not understand firearms, this is unlikely. The hard part about rifling is making them not the concept.

Comment: @NexTerren True part tolerance is only half about precision measurement of individual parts.

Comment: The best option would be introducing pre-industrial technology centuries before it actually was adopted. So the ability of producing early modern firearms during the early Roman Empire for instance.  Or introducing Roman military tactics and organisation from the early Empire to the Greeks a century or two earlier. Or the benefits of masonry and artillery to the Celts of southern Britain before the Romans showed up.

Comment: See also: [the science of flatness](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWa3F4bKJsE)

Comment: @NexTerren: That story about over-precision in the B-52 restorations sounds fascinating; can you give a link to read more about it?  I googled a bit but couldn’t find anything about the over-precision aspect.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine It's from a talk given at an Oshkosh Airshow by the people who restored Doc: https://www.b29doc.com/, I didn't read it online, but I'll see if I can dig something up.

Comment: @NexTerren - "...restore WWII B-52 bombers to flight" There were no WWII B-52 bombers. The first prototype B-52 did not fly till 1952.

Comment: The story with the bombers is similar to the Apollo-era rocket motors.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovD0aLdRUs0

Comment: By far the most correct answer.

Comment: @NexTerren of course you mean the B-**25** not the B-52.

Answer (score 7):

## Springfield Model 1861

[image: Easy to manufacture, deadly]

As long as you go to a place where people have no problem creating iron swords and equipment you should be able to get them to create a (initially probably unrifled) version of this gun that works with a minimum of tools.

At first your engineers (let's assume you go to India at 100 BCE and start your conquest from there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_metallurgy_in_the_Indian_subcontinent#Iron and elephants hate being shot at by guns) will probably turn out something more akin to the Brown Bess rifle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_Bess. But this is fine! You are taking the Springfield muzzle loader because it was one of the last muzzle loaders in use, so it contains all the useful features that you'd like to eventually be implemented, but even a poor copy will be very functional.

I highly recommend using minié balls as soon as possible for ammunition. These are cheap to produce and very powerful, and will have no problem punching through any shields (think the shields of the Roman empire) or horses (think Parthian horsemen). The rate of fire will be approximately 3 RPM, which means that archers will actually have a rate of fire advantage over you, and might even have an accuracy advantage too while you are still using unrifled muskets. However this brings me to the most important advantage of using muskets over bows:

### "No" training required

While you are still using the brown bess version, an individual musketman would probably be at a disadvantage to say, a trained Parthian horse archer. However, training a soldier to use a musket takes weeks, training a soldier to wield a bow takes years, not to mention the costs associated with horses and the logistics required to field them.

Your greatest advantage will therefore be the size of the armies you can field. With massed musket fire, no enemy troops will be able to get close to you. Nonetheless, issuing a detachable bayonet to every troop will be highly recommended since it allows them to hold the line while the second (and optionally third) lines keep up their withering fire.

To sustain such large armies, you'll need to bring 2 additional items:

- A handbook on medicine and hygiene: before the 20th century (and even during it), most casualties in armies were caused by disease. Without hygiene, and proper training of your officers about where to setup camp and how to guarantee a proper water supply, your army might quickly have plenty of guns, but not enough people to use them!
- A book on constructing a field kitchen: The field kitchen allowed armies to cook the meals for soldiers, thereby severely reducing the amount of time spend by soldiers on foraging and cooking their food, and therefore massively increasing how far your army can move in a day. You will need to move quickly to giving other empires the time to copy your firearm design and field their own versions.

Comment: A flintlock requires spring steel.  You're much better off with a matchlock, which can be built from any metal strong enough to handle the pressure of firing.

Comment: Wootz steel already exits in India at this point. You'll just have to scale up the process, but if your hero reads up a bit on the Bessemer process, it should be possible. As mentioned in my comment, I do not expect them to immediately replicate a perfect firearm, and if certain sections of it cannot be replicated, they can be replaced by even simpler designs for the time being.

Comment: Seconding @Jonas -- the steel billets for Damascus swords came from up-country India, where the natural iron had some manganese and vanadium in it.  Even watchspring steel made from that iron would work for the frizzen, which is the only part that absolutely has to be hardenable steel (flat springs, as in pre-1900 lockwork, can be Damascus or crucible steel).

Comment: You are underestimating the quality of steel needed to withstand firing, inconsistent steel will just get your men killed.

Comment: I've often read that archery needs years of training, from my experience, that's not the case unless you go for ranges (kill range, where you can expect to hit a 30x30cm target) over 50m (needing bows >70lbs) or very high firing rates > 10/min. Two weeks. Four, if you need to grow a few muscles. The medieval archers shot 120lbs bows, that's a bit different. Useful to pierce plate armour.

Comment: @Karl The years of training is precisely because war bows are not hunting bows - the power needed to penetrate armor (not just plate - any armor is difficult to penetrate) puts the draw weight beyond the physical ability of individuals who have not trained for extensive periods (not so much a skill issue as one of muscle development like heavy weight training). Achieving long distance was not an objective because arrows lose power in flight so they generally shot from close range (the high arcing ballistics is mostly just a thing of movies).

Comment: @pluckedkiwi point taken, but you don't need years to get up to 80lbs. I know one guy who has one, and that's a frightning piece of hardware, compared to my own 45lbs. Arrows go through 3mm of steel at 30m. The 150lbs bows found on the Mary Rose were for naval warfare, which I guess meant longer distances. Do we actually *know* that land armies used such heavy bows?

Comment: @Karl those were not some kind of "special bow for naval combat" - those were simply war bows, and that huge strength is both why they were effective and why archers needed to train continually for many years in order to use them. Even then they were not generally able to penetrate good armor - they still hoped to batter the enemy and maybe find a gap (armor was effective or they wouldn't bother wearing such heavy restrictive expensive high-maintenance stuff - which is why most armor went away with better firearms).

Comment: I have to wonder if introducing 20th century field hygiene, field medicine, and field kitchens _alone_ would make enough of a difference in any preindustrial society, to the point that bringing back advanced firearms would be superfluous.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with reproducing modern firearms in pre-industrial civilizations would be:

- steel of inadequate quality
- lack of precision tools
- lack of an industry capable of manufacturing smokeless gunpowder.
- severely limited possibilities for economics of scale.

The cause why people in the middle ages didn't make cartridge-based automatic firearms wasn't because the idea didn't occur to them. The reason why many inventions weren't "discovered" much sooner was that they lacked the economical and industrial base to manufacture them efficiently and economically.

Actually, some repeating firearm designs already emerged around the 16th-17th century, but they were so impractical that repeaters didn't get useful and widespread until the late 19th century. Those early designs were so expensive to make and so difficult to maintain, that they never saw widespread use.

Even if, with a lot of handwaving and a lot of luck you managed to [replicate](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/10610/262) a modern firearm in a pre-industrial age, it would be of questionable quality and reliability, and as cartridges have to be manufactured at an extremely high level of precision, you would basically require the most experienced master jeweler to manufacture each and every cartridge by hand, possibly requiring most of a day just to make a single one. And then you would have a "modern" firearm of extremely poor reliability with a high likelihood to jam, break, or explode in your face after every shot, with ammunition so expensive that for the cost to make one full magazine you could hire a whole army of mercenaries.

This is why those early repeaters, made many centuries before repeating firearms became commonplace, didn't have cartridges. They had a reservoir of loose gunpowder and loose lead balls, and an intricate clockwork mechanism driven by a had-crank which performed the motions of loading a traditional muzzle-loader. Yes, they had, for their time, an amazing and unparalleled rate of fire! Still, they were too expensive and too difficult to maintain to see any widespread use. Every single part needed to be made individually, and you couldn't use spare parts from one gun to repair another one. An army requires weapons they can maintain and repair in the field, you can't drag your kingdom's most experienced master smith and his whole workshop with you wherever you go. And even if you do, he alone couldn't maintain the guns of a whole army of tens of thousands. This was one of the reasons why the Girandoli air rifle [failed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UhCx0b2ZC4Q) so miserably. I recommend to watch the linked video, because it explains well why extremely powerful but expensive and complicated weapon systems often fail against less powerful but cheaper mass produced ones. For a complex piece of equipment you need a complex infrastructure to keep it in working order. You can't just put it into a soldier's hands and hope you've done all the work.

So, the highest level of weapons technology you could ever hope to replicate (and use in an effective and efficient way) in pre-industrial times, would be **muskets with Minié balls, and cap-and-ball revolvers**. They became obsolete 150 years ago, and even they would be just on the very verge of possibility. Anything newer, you can forget about it. But even these Minié rifles would be much more effective than what your opponents would field, giving you great advantage.

Answer (score 3):

He should bring back a replica firearm from a historical period as close as possible to the one he's trying to dominate.  The precision manufacturing and metallurgy and chemistry of the time will fundamentally limit reproduction, so picking something that could already nearly be made will help tremendously.

Note that he still has his work cut out for him.  Despite outward appearances, guns don't always mean you win.  It takes training.  In particular, training entire militaries is a very time consuming task that may require multiple lifetimes to achieve.

For a cinemagraphic depiction of this, consider the first part of *The Last Samaurai*.  Fighting against trained warriors when you are unfamiliar with the tactics regarding how to use a weapon, nor the strategies which let you leverage it, can go spectacularly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to do two frame challenges: firearms are not the best way to do this and the hero can't achieve his goal.

First of all, as others have stated, **modern** firearms are made with modern tools and modern materials, which simply won't be available to the hero back whenever he wants to go (presuming he wants to go back when modern firearms would have a big enough impact). Non-modern firearms or knowledge about them can indeed be useful, and the hero could very conceivably introduce gunpowder and cannons to the early middle ages, rendering most (if not all) castles of that age VERY vulnerable to your army. The problem here is that your army so far consists of the hero and his cannon.

You see, your hero is still just a peasant, even if he possesses some magical stick that can kill at a distance even through armor, or some cart that can hurt a castle. His best bet is to hire some blacksmith to build the parts, produce the gunpowder himself and sell the weapons, which can turn him into a very wealthy merchant very quickly, but you're putting these advanced weapons in the hands of anyone who can pay for them (and who will eventually oppose you when you want to conquer them along with the whole world). Still, we might be on to something.

Since your hero needs to hire/get **his own** army (arming a noble's servants is actually a good deal, but doesn't make **the hero** the ruler of the world), he'll need either noble blood (good luck with that), a huge wealth or a noble title (acquired, not inherited). The last two can actually be achieved in a similar fashion: bring back something other than firearms, some knowledge or technique (or even better, multiple ones) that allow you to mass produce or somehow acquire something of value which he can sell for huge wealth, or that he can sell the secret itself in exchange for nobility and vassals. A wide array of techniques and knowledge works best, for example faster, ocean-faring ships to support your trading empire (plus they will help a lot later on with your conquest), irrigation techniques (you will eventually become a ruler, and you need to keep your empire fed), and just a general understanding of logistics, law, ethics, anything that helps your empire last until you conquer the whole world. Which brings us to our final problem (and second frame challenge).

**Your hero can't conquer the whole world in his lifetime.** The world is simply too big to conquer with the general level of technology that your hero needs to encounter to make modern firearms game-changing enough to even give him a shot at conquest. I would even argue that the world is too big to conquer with any pre-nuclear technology.

One option would be to reduce the size of the world. Build a bunker, detonate enough nuclear warheads to kill all life on Earth, and now "the world" is your bunker, where your hero can rule until his probably very early death.

Answer (score 1):

**A MkI Gatling Gun**

If it'll fit inside your time machine, a Gatling Gun and as much ammo as you can fit.  The crank version invented in 1861, you may remember its effect against pre-gunpowder armies from "The Last Samura." Provided your Hero knows what fulminate of mercury is.  Now I know what you're all thinking, "That's almost impossible for anyone to make! You'd need jewelers to make the cartridges and assembly!" My answer is, "why yes, yes you would."  Your hero's problem is any gun less technologically advanced than a Springfield rifle is going to be less effective than a bow and arrow.  There's a reason firearms were around for hundreds of years and considered gimmick weapons as much as anything else.  You'd need to turn them out in their thousands and have ammunition by the ton before your army would be superior to what it was before you turned up! That kind of investment is simply impossible for most ancient civilizations.  Too many people not farming or herding or doing any of the other things you need to do to keep people alive.

A Gatling gun, on the other hand, is a comparatively minor investment in resources.  Couple dozen blacksmiths and jewelers for the fine work of springs and cartridges and everything else is relatively simple.  A battery of 6 divided into 2-gun sections can cover about 2280 meters of battlefield (effective range of 918 meters, leave room for overlapping fire).  A pike phalanx of the Macedonian variety has about 1 square meter of space per soldier before they tighten up still further at close range.  Other mass-infantry formations tend to stick to 1 square meter for each man.  So (and forgive my math, I'm a history major after all!) each section can cover a frontage of about 2280 block-infantry, which'll likely be at least 8 men deep, and maybe as many as 16.  In other words,  a section can fire at 20,000ish men in formations so dense you almost can't miss.  Probably less than 20,000 as individual units need space to maneuver, but the point is you'd need relatively few to cover an entire ancient battlefield.  Enemy infantry is effectively doomed. Too  lightly armored and they're torn to shreds at maximum range, and the more armor you pile on the slower they go, and the fewer of them your enemy  can field against you.

Against Mass Cavalry the odds become tougher.  Cavalry charged (and I'm using Napoleonic numbers here because we have the tactical manuals which give precise measurements.  I assume an armored cataphract would be a bit slower, but this is a good top-end speed) at about 20kph, so 5.5 meters per second or thereabouts.  That's a little less than 3 minutes to go from "maximum range" to "stabbing your gunners."  A single Gatling can pump out 200 rounds per minute, so lets say 500 rounds before the cav get yah.  Maybe less, since your gunners are unlikely to stand to their pieces when the cavalry is close!  But even so, that's enough weight of fire to break up all but the most determined cavalry.

The other big PRO for gatling guns is that, because they're relatively large and you need few of them, is that your enemies are MUCH less likely to figure them out.  Easy for a foe to steal a musket, or buy one from a shady supply soldier or get one from a deserter.  But Gatling guns are much harder to just walk off with.  Plus they become "prestige" weapons for your king/emperor/Hero, which is always a plus.

You also get the psychological impact of literally mowing down ranks of the enemy in ridiculously short amounts of time.  in 5 minutes your 6-gun battery will have fired about 12,000 rounds at the enemy.  Even if only a quarter of your rounds hit (likely, maybe even too high, because of a whole host of factors I won't get into) that's hundreds or thousands of the enemy dead and wounded.  Many at a range they weren't even expecting danger.  Despite the bloody toll of many ancient battles, actual COMBAT deaths (as opposed to massacred-while-running-away deaths) were generally few.  If you kill a couple thousand enemy while they're still 450 meters away (outside maximum bowshot) the whole army may well break under the pressure, leaving your forces to mop up.  Best bring a good amount of light cavalry with you!

A small but important upside to a Gatling Gun is that, once you know how to do that, you can also make things like siege Cannon with a little bit of experimentation.  Or standard muskets/rifles, but as I've mentioned before I think those aren't really useful in societies where 95-98% of the population has to farm or else there's a famine.

The downside, apart from your hero needing to lug your demo piece to the first king he comes across, is that they eat up ammo at a ferocious rate.  Which in turn means you still need a lot of materials.  For instance 40 cartridges (which you'd 100% want to recover after a battle) take a pound of brass.  If you have 12 guns and each one carries just 5 minutes of ammo, that's 300lbs of brass alone.  A lot, but still MUCH less than the material cost you'd incur for equipping 1,000 men with flintlocks.  Which again, wouldn't be as useful as 1,000 men with any number of different types of bow/crossbow.

Of course, what would likely end up winning your hero the war wouldn't be the firearm he brought back, but his insistence on basic sanitation.  But teaching a civilization to wash their hands and piss downstream is less fun than superior firepower!

Comment: and the first subpar round that wedges in the barrel makes it useless. keep in mind they will not even be able to make the casing brass.

Answer (score 0):

If your time traveler is trying to alter history by introducing "modern" firearms long before their time, his best bet would be an external hammer break-action shotgun (single or double), with brass cartridges loaded with black powder.  The cartridges should be a mix of birdshot, buckshot, and "pumpkin ball" slug loads.  Fixed chokes, no tighter than "improved modified", recommended.  That's enough to demonstrate the effect of choke on a shot column (especially if one barrel is cylinder and the other improved modified), but not so tight as to cause trouble with the round ball loads.

If he's got any chemistry knowledge at all, he can make primers that will work, brass was a known and worked metal even in ancient times, and black powder shotguns can be made with pretty primitive steel (or even bronze) for the barrel and lockwork.

With a source of cartridges, a competent smith from 1600 (possibly as far back as 1500) could build a shotgun that could fire modern cartridges.  It wouldn't be a nice to fire as a modern one (heavier, for one thing), but it would work.  Once they have working firearms, the advancement can begin -- they'll be effectively up to 1860 technology as soon as they can make cartridges and that gun.

Answer (score 0):

Why is he bringing a gun to duplicate?  He should be bringing books!  The gun would only be to demonstrate what the objective is, it need not be copied.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to disagree with some of the naysayers and point out that as soon as gunpowder is discovered, they have all the technology they need to make any manual action gun.  Revolvers, bolt action, lever action, break action or pump action long guns are all possible.

Some posters have pointed out that pre-modern metallurgy is not up to our standards.  I agree.  But you don't need it to be.  You can simply use thicker chambers, and remember, black powder produces much less pressure than modern smokeless powder.

Some have pointed out that pre-modern machining is nowhere near as good as modern machining.  Again, I agree.  And again, with manual action guns you don't absolutely need it to be.  Semiautomatic or automatic guns need machined precise to the micron because they work together.  Every part has to work together precisely or the whole thing won't work.  Manual action guns on the other hand have much looser tolerances.  Tighter tolerances are still nice, but loose ones are not dealbreakers.

The key is to not just bring back a gun or blueprints for a gun, but also the recipe for fulminated mercury so you can make cartridges.

Comment: The problem is *volume*.  Prior to about the mid-1800s, the only people who can make cartridges with the precision needed are jewelers.  That rather limits the rate at which you can produce ammunition, and drives up the price.

Comment: I'd think anyone making coins could make cartridges.  The principles are almost the same, for straight-walled, centerfire cartridges.

Comment: Historically, coin-making was not a precision operation.  Sure, the metal you're starting from is precisely divided up (by weight), but then you place the roughly-formed blank between the dies, smack the whole thing with a hammer, and you're done.

Comment: Cartridges need deep draw dies, not surface dies like a coin. These were not perfected until the late 1800's.

Comment: @Thucydides What about shotgun shells?  Early shotgun shells used cardboard hulls, not plastic.

Comment: @Ryan_L Actually, *early* shotgun shells were straight walled brass (you can still buy those, if you want them).  Paper hulls didn't come along until 1880 or so.

Comment: @ZeissIkon just because paper hull didn't come out till then does not mean they could not be made.  Cardboard is so easy to make that the adhesives and tools needed to make it happen are practically stone-aged. You could make a cardboard cylinder, and use on a surface die pressed backing 2000+ years ago no problem.

Comment: @Ryan_L : such guns actually did exist. There were some repeating firearms almost 300 years before repeaters really started becoming commonplace. They never got successful. The "naysayers" don't say it's completely impossible to make them, just that they won't be all that useful due to lots of reasons. Mainly cost and the huge infrastructure required to maintain them.

Comment: thinker chamber becomes a problem, because thick enough means to heavy to carry. the firearms you discuss DO need much higher levels of precision than is available if you want them to fire more than once. a misaligned cylinder on a revolver or a broken firing pin creates a paperweight if you are lucky Most of those also need gun-brass equivalent cartridges to work.

Answer (score -1):

Making firearms may not work out but just go back further. The Greek shields and 20' spears allowed them to dominate the world. A Roman general said getting through 3 layers of spear points to be able to start fighting Greeks was the hardest battles he fought. Greek fire won naval battles. The Romans interlocking shields won for them. The Indian's using elephants as a shooting platform dominated war in its sphere. The Chinese cross bow allowed one Chinese emperer to overcome all his rivals and unite China. The Mongul's horses dominated the plains. Just changing some tactics and fighting skills allowed Shaka Zulu to dominate southern Africa. The first chariots gave an incredible advantage. Catapaults and trebuckets changed war throughout europe and the known civilized world. Hot air baloons made observation and communications leap forward. The various armor changed and evolved. The long bow had it's own influence. Compound bows would allow distance and accuracy seldom available throughout history.

If you go back before these inventions, you can apply all of them at once and be virtually invincible. Now you just need to learn ancient Sumarian. Going back before written language would again be a HUGE advantage to the first warlord to use it for communications.

Comment: It's not these "inventions" which won the wars, long pikes and shields could have been easily manufactured thousands of years earlier, had they seen any use for them. It's the social structure, high level of organization, training, and discipline which made possible to use them effectively. People were not stupid. If you go back to a late stone age or early bronze age settlement and say *"hey, make longer spears"*, the reaction won't be *"wow, thanks, this idea never occurred to us"*.

Comment: Same can be said of guns. It is a matter of degree. Guns made it better but without the training, organization and discipliine guns still do not make the difference. John Smith broke his pistol lest the indians learn his gun fired less far than their arrows.  Other Spaniards helped a native American tribe against their enemies and got slaughtered. Still there are weapons giving the edge that changed history fairly regularly. The advent of gun powder made a difference but it still evolved over hundreds of years to get where we are today.

Comment: Actually, the earliest guns had the less need of training and physical fitness as their biggest advantage.